# How should children nodes be passed to a ReactComponent

Tags: scalajs-react

I've been using scalajs-react for a couple of weeks and so far I've never used the "children" parameter of ReactComponentC.apply() because my children ReactNodes are usually conditionally defined in c.backend.render().
Am I doing something wrong? I there an advantage with passing the children nodes in ReactComponentC.apply()? I there any way to modify this children list dynamically after ReactComponentC.apply() has been run?

Basically I'm just wondering what's the advantage of passing a child to ReactComponentB versus creating an instance of ReactComponentB within the render method of the father component.
For instance:

```
    class Backend($: BackendScope[Props, State]) { //The backend class of the father
  def render(p: Props, s: State) = {
     ReactComponentB("Child") //I create the child directly in the render method (I didn't pass it as a Child.Varargs)
  }
}
```

Comment: For those wondering how to create a component that accept children: https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/issues/83#issuecomment-1064872840

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean. 1.0.0-RC1 has just been released and children are handled differently now anyway. If you upgrade to it, read the new [TYPES.md](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/TYPES.md) and [changelog](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/changelog/1.0.0.md) you might find that this question has become obsolete...?

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm gonna update to 1.0.0. But I think my question is still relevant for 1.0.0. I added a bit of clarification to my question above.